# CodeXL crashing during clCreateContext

Tags: opencl, amd-gpu, codexl

I'm trying to use CodeXL 2.5 Under Ubuntu 16.04 with `amdgpupro` driver.

While OpenCL add (aka Hello World) is running from the command line in CodeXL it's simply crashing at `clCreateContext`.

Do you have any idea how to get GPU Profiling (Performance counters) working?
Any alternative to CodeXL?

Answer (score 0):

Okey

Let me answer as I found solution.
CodeXL is a mess currently and not working for GPU profiling for me under Ubuntu, Win7 64, Win10 64.

To make it work I end up running `rcprof` command line tool. It is working and generating session files which you can later import in CodeXL by creating empty project and - 'Import Session'.
This way you can get GPU performance counters and API Traces.